# Array of strings convert to XML DOM

Tags: javascript, html, xml, parsing, dom

I have the following array of strings, note that in my case the arrays will never exceed the lenght of 4

```
["Scott","Bill","Basketball","2000"]
```

To give you some context, I have this array stored on the Local Storage on my browser. Ok, now I'm getting stuck at "morphing" this array into an XML. Let me explain, 
I'm looking for a thing like that

```
<root>
     <person>
            <pnane>Scott</pname>
            <psurname>Bill</pname>
            <pnane>Basketball</pname>
            <pnane>2000</pname>
     </person>
</root>
```

So summing it up, I'm looking for transforming an array of strings and passing the values of it into a XML pre-defined template.

Any thoughts/light on this?

Thanks ;)

Comment: if this was an html page it would be quite easy to do. I never used Xml. Can the values within the array be assigned in the form of innerHtml with the same logic ?

Comment: @CanUver Yes, the problem is that those values, Scott,Bill... Are taken from the users input on a form, getting the info using the **document.getElementsByClassName**

Comment: can you be a little more specific, so I can understand you better ?

Comment: Yes, sorry English is quite hard for me. What I mean is you can easly assign via innerHTML. @CanUver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jquery easy to convert xml object

```js
var arr= ["Scott&","Bill<test>","Basketball","2000"]
var xmlStr="<root><person>";
xmlStr+="<pname>"+removeSpecialchars(arr[0])+"</pname>"
xmlStr+="<psurname>"+removeSpecialchars(arr[1])+"</psurname>"
xmlStr+="<psuppot>"+removeSpecialchars(arr[2])+"</psuppot>"
xmlStr+="<pyear>"+removeSpecialchars(arr[3])+"</pyear>"
xmlStr+="</person></root>";


var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlStr,"text/xml");

console.log(xmlDoc.documentElement.innerHTML);

function removeSpecialchars(el) {
   return el.replace(/&/g, '&amp;amp;')
            .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
            .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/'/g, '&apos');
}
```

Comment: Can't it be done with vanilla JS? No external plugins

Comment: Terrible answer, it totally ignores the possibility that the strings will contain special characters like `&` or `<`. We get so many SO posts from people having to cope with bad XML caused by this kind of carelessness.